# Reclassify not working two times

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, reclassify

My code runs like this:

```
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""Int(RoundUp("time_min"))""",path+"/Time_int")
arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("D:/Flash Flood/Python/Reclassify.xlsx",path+"/reclassify","5")
arcpy.gp.ReclassByTable_sa("Time_int","reclassify","From_","To","New",path+"/Rectime","DATA")
Classify = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(12)
arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("D:/Flash Flood/Python/Reclassify.xlsx",path+"/reclasviz",Classify)#error
arcpy.gp.ReclassByTable_sa("Time_int","reclasviz","From_","To","New",path+"/Viz","DATA")
```

For some reason the second reclassify doesn't work. Why is it so? The input itself runs into a problem. This is only when I run the whole program. If I just separately run the last 3 lines providing the layers, it works fine. The Excel file has classification limits.

Comment: Start by using `os.path.join` to combine paths to fix potential path errors. Change `path+"/reclasviz",Classify` to `os.path.join(path, "reclasviz", Classify)` etc. What are you inputing in `GetParameterAsText(12)`? Are you sure that Sheet name exists?

Comment: Yeah, so I found out the input is not registering for some reason. I post another question for it.